# How to change spaces in URL laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello everyone I'm trying to link to single product but I want to change spaces to "-" beetwen words. For example I have name of product Example Product and Laravel generate url: Example%20Product. I tried do it by myself but it doesn't work I delete spaces in php but when I add "-" links are broken. Here is my routes and view

```
Route::get('/prod/{prodName}-{id}', 'ProductController@getSingleProduct')->where('prodName', '\w+ ');

@foreach($products as $product)
<div class="col-md-12 item">
    <?php $series = str_replace(' ', '-', $product->name); 
        $series1 = strtolower($series);
    ?>                          
    <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/prod/{{$series1}}-{{$product->id}}"><img src="{{URL::to('/')}}/images/{{$product->photo}}.jpg" class="img-responsive thumb pull-left" alt="">
        <div class="desc">
            <h3>{{$product->name}} </h3>
            {{$product->id}}
            <img src="images/review2.png" alt="" class="pull-left"><p>4 of 3 reviews</p>
            <p class="latest-rev"><span>Latest Review:</span> {{$latestReview[0]->description}}  </p>
        </div> 
    </a>    
</div>
@endforeach
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When you say "links are broken" what is the actual url that you are getting when you output `{{URL::to('/')}}/prod/{{$series1}}-{{$product->id}}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's

```
Str::slug('My favourite product');
```

returns:

```
my-favourite-product
```

so you could use this. So just:

```
{{Str::slug($product->name)}}
```

is what you want.

Now by following this policy you cause a routing problem. Laravel is told with your route declaration that after the very first `-` whatever comes after is the `id` parameter. When your url is this:

```
http://www.mypage.com/my-nice-product-115
```

then Laravel thinks that the word `my` is the parameter named `prodName` and the rest of it meaning `nice-product-115` is the parameter named `id`. So this will never work.

If i were you i would use a url like:

```
http://www.mypage.com/115/my-nice-product
```

and in my controller's method i would match the `id` parameter etc. The route also would be:

```
Route::get('/prod/{id}/{prodName}', ['as'=>'product.show', 'uses' => 'ProductController@getSingleProduct']);
```

and i would certainly take advantage of `Str::slug()` method i mentioned before. So to call it into action:

```
{{route('product.show', [$product->id, Str::slug($product->name)])}}
```

would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably your route:

```
Route::get('/prod/{prodName}-{id}', 'ProductController@getSingleProduct')->where('prodName', '\w+ ');
```

You have white space at the end. You should change it into:

```
Route::get('/prod/{prodName}-{id}', 'ProductController@getSingleProduct')->where('prodName', '[\w-]+');
```

to don't allow space and allow `-` in prodName

Now when you have space at the end it means that this space is required to match `prodName`

Comment: When I deleted it and my link looks like example-product-1. I clicked on it and it doesn't works. But link exampleproduct-1 works well. I need "-" between words.

Comment: @Zolax I see, so you should probably change it into `[\w-]+`. However I don't know what is your id requirements (you don't have any in where part) and if product name can contain also numbers. If yes, it might a problem, because route won't know how to match `-` - is it separator between prodName and id or part of prodName. So maybe you should consider also other separator between prodName and id (that is never contained inside prodName) for example `,`. But I don't know, so first you should check simple using `[\w-]+` instead of `\w+`

Comment: Thank you very much it works. I have one more question because now works two links example-product and exampleproduct is there a way to delete working exampleproduct link?

Comment: @Zolax Probably you check your url in getSingleProduct of ProductController. So you should look at the code because you probably allow there 2 types using some function (for example `str_replace`)

Comment: yes I change product name spaces to "-" using `$series = str_replace(' ', '-', $product->name); 
        $series1 = strtolower($series);` is there another way to do it and got only one type of links?

Comment: But this code you use when creating links. And what code do you use in controller when you want to make action to specific product?

Comment: Im getting all products from specific category in this way: 
Route: `Route::get('/prod/{prodName}-{id}', 'ProductController@getSingleProduct')->where('prodName', '[\w-]+');`
Action:
`public function getSingleProduct($prodName, $id)
 {    
  $singleProduct = Product::getOne($id);
  $getAllReviews = Review::getAllBelongsToProduct($id);

  // get paginated
  $reviews = Review::forReview($id)->withProductPhoto()->latest()->paginate(2);
  $this->layout->content = View::make('products.single')
          ->with('reviews', $reviews)
          ->with('products', $singleProduct);
 }`
Sorry for format.

Comment: Solution is very simple. I see you only use `$id` to get product. After getting product from database, you should use `$series = str_replace(' ', '-', $product->name);  $series1 = strtolower($series);` - it should be done on product from database and then you should simple compare it with `prodName` you got from your route. If they not match, you should make 301 redirection to correct url

Comment: hmm I don't understand everything can we chat somewehere cause I'm from Poland too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57682/discussion-between-marcin-nabialek-and-zolax).